# image processing

Tags: java, image-processing

I want to change the value of the pixels in an image, for which i need to store the image as a matrix. How can i perform this job? Please guide.

Answer (score 6):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(..);
image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
```

Check the documentation of [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly read the image into a BufferedImage.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
```

Then create matrix like structure in the 2D array like this and set RGB:

```
for(int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++){
     image.setRGB(i, j, rgb);  
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Image is 2d representation of data (pixel info)
- 2D means x&y directions. In case of image, these directions are generally treated as rows & columns
- To change the pixel value, we have to get its location in these rows and columns
- Getting pixel location is like that class teacher addressing the unknown student with his sitting position (ex:2nd bench 3rd person)
- Like this we have to address the pixel by its rows and column location